# .on() not working for dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, dynamically-generated

I'll try and explain what I'm trying to do as clearly as I can and hopefully people'll be able to understand the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.mainNav', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body').load(href);
   });
});
```

This is the bit of code which has been causing me trouble. Basically what it's -supposed- to do is grab the 'href' attribute from a div and then load that to replace the current content of the body tag.

This works the first time but when the new content is generated via .load() the div stops responding. I'm pretty new to JS so I apologize in advance if the answer is something obvious. I've been trying to find a solution on my own but everything I find tells me that .on() should work for dynamically generated content.

**EDIT:** Can't emulate the problem in a fiddle so I'm posting a pastebin with the entire index page in hopes of it clarifying the problem.

http://pastebin.com/xT5syd9j

**EDIT:** It works using adeneo's solution. Much obliged to everyone for their input and apologies for not posting the entire thing from the start. I'm guessing it would've saved everyone some time.

Comment: `.load` is based on Ajax which means that `href` can only be URLs based on the same domain as the script. This is called the same origin policy. It could be that `href` is `http://google.com`. This would break the script.

Comment: If you don't get errors on the page [it should just work](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/rPSJ5/).

Comment: @PeeHaa you're using the `html()` method, not the `load()` method. It's different, so not a proof case.

Comment: @CSED: Do you have `<script>` tags to load external JS inside `<body>`? Most specifically, do you load jQuery itself in this way? If so, move jQuery inside `<head>` and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: @Jon: There are no script tags inside the body. Everything's in head. I'm making the fiddle now so hopefully that can cross the barrier of me being terrible at explanations.

Comment: What is usually in the `href` attribute?

Comment: @Purmou: Sorry, didn;t see the comment. The href attribute contains a relative link to the page so, href="test.php". The link is valid and tested.

Comment: The link is NOT valid, it's a fracking div with a href attribute !

Comment: FYI, on StackOverflow, you are NOT supposed to edit your title to include "SOLVED".  The green checkmark you apply indicates to everyone that you have a solution.

Comment: Ah. I'll remove it then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the issue it, but I'm guessing it has something to do with loading into the same element as the handler is attached to, so try :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.mainNav', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('I just clicked : '+e.target.href);
        $('body').load(e.target.href);
    });
});
```

Also, you are of course aware that this will replace ALL content on your page, and unless there is a new element with the same class in the loaded content, nothing will happen. I would suggest using a container for loading the content into aswell. And of course, the links has to be to actual files on your server.

Also make sure the files you load does not have another set of `<head>`, `<body>` tags etc. as that will mess things up for you, HTML content only!

**EDIT:**

If `.mainNav` is a `<a href="link_you_are_trying_to_load"></a>` type of element, you will have to prevent the default action as well, see updated code.

**NEW EDIT:**

The problem you are having is pretty obvious, you are using elements like :

```
<div class="mainNav" href="test.php" id="active">
```

a div element has no attribute href, so JS will not get that value as it's not a valid attribute for anything other than a `<a>` element

You can either change your element to an `<a>` element or change the href attribute to:

```
<div class="mainNav" data-href="test.php" id="active">
```

and do:

```
var href = $(this).data('href');
```

at least that would be valid HTML!

Also, you seem to have a "container" like element called `#site` so why don't you do :

```
$('#site').load(href); //using the data-href as above
```

Comment: "I'm guessing it has something to do with loading into the same element as the handler is attached to" -> Shouldn't matter

Comment: @ErikE: And I agree with PeeHaa. Why does that matter? What matters is that the docs say the *content* of the element is replaced, not the element itself. I actually tried a variant on this very page, and the JS console gives me errors that hint to jQuery being "unloaded" after the first `.load` call.

Comment: It should'nt have anything to do with it, but stranger things have happened, and there's not much to debug in those few lines of code, either the href is wrong or something is happening with the load() function.

Comment: This isn't working. The div isn't responding to the click at all now. The href is valid, checked it. And the file it points to doesn't have head or body tags. It starts out at the first div after body. I'll try to remake the entire thing in a fiddle since I get the feeling that this might be a case of me explaining something poorly. Give me a few minutes and thanks for the fast responses.

Comment: @CSED . I just added a console.log to my answer, try using that and check the browser console to see what's happening when you click the elements, and what href you get back. Plain JS href will often include the domain name, while jQuery usually gets the href given in the HTML etc. but atleast that will show you that the links really work.

Comment: I can't believe I completely forgot about `preventDefault()`. >.< That's the painfully obvious solution here...

Comment: @adeneo: Using your code the console reports undefined as the link being used, which is odd since using the chrome dev tools the link appears to be valid when I click it.

Comment: @CSED - See my updated answer, you can not, and should not, use href attributes with any other element than `<a>`

Comment: @adeneo The #site is just a container div for #mainContainer, it's also the first div in the href page being linked to. I wasn't aware that elements other than a shouldn't have a href attribute. I'll give your solution a try and report back. I thought that might be it but the href in the div actually worked for the first link, before the content was changed via load so I assumed a div could have a href attribute. This might have just been error handling from the browser though.

Comment: Yes, you can attach a href attribute to any element, and in most newer browsers it will work, but it's not valid, and in most cases it will not work with javascript, and even if it did, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @Jon Okay I agree with you now. I was proved wrong by the docs that say the element is not replaced but only its contents. It shouldn't lose its click handler.

Comment: @adeneo: It works. I'm almost crying tears of joy here. The problem was my stupid use of the href attribute, should've just posted the entire thing from the start. Would have clarified a lot of things. Much obliged for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here **may** be what you really load when you invoke `$('body').load(href)`. If you load the HTML of the whole page (including `<html>` and `<body>` tags), then you may have a problem. Your browser works with such issues by making something usable from incorrect HTML (which is in your case something like `<html><body><html><body>...</body></html></body></html>`) - which may give unexpected results.

The better idea is to:

1. Organize HTML properly (see below)
2. Load only part of the HTML generated above, when you load it with `$(...).load()`.

Ad.1. Make sure you have some element just below `<body>` tag, that has own ID and contains everything that would be located in `<body>` tag. It may look like that:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <div id="main_div">
    <!-- all elements here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ad.2. Loading such content is a lot easier, as you can **append a selector** to the URL passed to `.load()` (see "*Loading Page Fragments*" on [jQuery `.load()` docs page](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

```
$('body').load(href + ' #main_div');
```

This way you will retrieve whole page, but get only the element with ID "`#main_div`" and replace the whole `<body>` content with it.

This way events attached to body (even these delegated) should still work properly.

Comment: No need to add another element inside `body`.

Comment: @Purmou: You are right, but it is good to have the code organized that way, if it is supposed to work like that. Selecting element by ID is a lot faster than using eg. `body > *` selector proposed by you. If you can, you should stick to selecting elements by their IDs only (unless not reasonable).

Comment: @Tadeck: The page I'm trying to load doesn't contain html/head/body tags. The structure is exactly as you pointed out, a div containing everything that I want replaced, so when I replace the contents of body I replace a large div. I think that's what you were trying to point out as a possible problem.

Comment: @CSED: Ok, so you are saying the page that the browser pulls from the server is already cropped to only that element. What about `<script>` tags? Does it contain any? What about the elements that do not respond: do they have custom `onclick` (etc.) attributes? And one more thing: Are you sure you are using `.on()` and not `.one()`? Because it would clarify a lot ;)

Comment: @Tadeck: No script tags, however adeneo's solution worked. The problem was my idiotic use of the href attribute. Thanks a bunch for all the input though.

Comment: @CSED: Pretty unexpected ;) But since his answer helped, I think you should accept it. It is good you have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.mainNav', function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('body').load(href + " body > *");
    });
});
```

What we do here is load only the contents of the body element on the page (`href`). There's no need to add more elements to that page. Just select the contents of the body like Tradeck mentioned.

The problem is obviously that if the page at `href` is a full HTML page, you're loading in a DOCTYPE, a second `html` tag, a second `head` and `body` tag, etc.

Comment: It is exactly what I proposed, except without the element with separate ID. It should work, though.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yeah, my bad--I didn't load the new answers while I was writing my own. :P Though we have very distinct options here, so I think we're fine. :)

Comment: I don't have issues with that. I just said it should work as well as my own answer works ;) Your answer does not require changes to the page HTML, mine proposes such changes and works faster. Anyway, don't delete your own, it adds some value.

Comment: @Purmou: Didn't know about this, thanks. But it doesn't matter much since the page being loaded via the href doesn't contain a body tag, only a div which the original page also contains, so the content of body is being replaced using the full page from the href link, not body. Thanks though.